# Retrieve current password from Active director using Apache LDAP API

Tags: java, active-directory

I have a use case where i want to reset the password for user. Before i reset their password, i want them to check their password within Active Directory and only if the current password is correct they should be able to change their password.

I need to know how can i retrieve the current password of the user from active directory using Apache LDAP Api.

```
 entryCursor = connection.search(searchRequest);
            if(null!=entryCursor){
                Entry user = entryCursor.getEntry();
                Iterator<Attribute> attr = user.getAttributes().iterator();
                while(attr.hasNext()){
// I assumed that unicodePwd would be part of attribute set, but looks like it is not.
                    Attribute currentAttribute = (Attribute) attr.next();
                    currentAttribute.getAttributeType();
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking the wrong question here. You can't get the password, as it is hashed, and you don't need it. You just need to try to bind as that user with what he claims is his current password. If that succeeded, it was correct and you can proceed to change it. If it fails, it wasn't.

It's always wrong to compare passwords. Let the system do the work. Another example, SQL this time:

```
select password from users where username = ?
```

followed by a password comparison, should instead be:

```
select count(*) as count from users where username = ? and password = ?
```

and check that `count == 1`.

This also has the advantage that you conceal, even from yourself, whether the username or the password was wrong if it failed. This is an important information privacy principle: you don't tell the attacker that he has found a valid username and now only has to guess the password.

Comment: I started thinking along those lines. Will update the post with details. Re authentication is the way to go.